# Arduino as keyboard on iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard, arduino

I'm trying to use a [makey makey](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/378) (a device based on the Arduino Leonardo) as a keyboard for an iPad. I know that it has [already been done](http://www.janefarrall.com/blog/2012/12/18/using-usb-switch-interfaces-with-switch-accessible-apps-on-your-ipad/), but I'm not able to reproduce it. My guess is that some versions of the iPad don't recognize this device.

Since I can use a USB keyboard and I know that mice are not recognized, I'd like to program the makey makey in such a way that it is "recognized only as a keyboard" (the original device can be used as a mouse and as a keyboard). I'm very new to Arduino, could someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Hey! Did you get this to work? I am working on a keyboard for iPhone, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague helped me for this issue and we were able to solve it. We just erased this line about [CDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class):

> #define CDC_ENABLED

in the file "USBDesc.h" (in the folder available on github: "firmware/Arduino/hardware/MaKeyMaKey/cores"). After doing this, there is a problem when compiling the code on the device, because the Arduino is not recognized anymore. You can still add your code to the Arduino, but you have to reset the device just after compilation start.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ProMicro 5v and a "Case Logic 2.0 USB Hub" and the Camera kit I was able to get the programed keyboard commands to be recognized by the iPad without modifying "USBDesc.h" file.

ProMicro has built in HID emulation support very similar to Arduino Leonardo. Besides the "USB IO Board: The connected device is not supported" error, the device is apparently unofficially supported. I believe this has something to do with the hub.

In my arduino code I am using the "Keyboard_ascii.h" library and am using Keyboard.print, and Keyboard.write commands to send the key commands / text to the iPad.